# get dict value in a list according to an order of key given

Tags: python

I have a dictionary as such:

```
dict = {1:a, 2:b, 3:c, 4:d}
```

I have a list of dict keys in a list already:

```
keys_order = [4, 2, 3, 1]
```

Given the info above, I want to create a list with 'values' of the `dict` according to the order of `keys_order`.

Expected result:

```
values_order = [d, b, c, a]
```

How should I do it?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: `values_order = [dict[x] for x in values_order]`, but note that you should give `dict` another name.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}
keys_order = [4, 2, 3, 1]
values_order = []

for key in keys_order:
    values_order.append(dict[key])

print(values_order)
```

Output:

```
['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```